# How can I monkey patch PyQT's QApplication.notify() to time events

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, profiling

In our PyQt application we want to time the duration of all Qt Events. Only in a special performance monitoring mode. Previously I subclassed QApplication and overrode the `notify()` method and that worked great. I wrote the data in `chrome://tracing` format and it was super helpful.

However when our application is run inside Jupyter there is a pre-existing QApplication instance. So I can't think of how to make it use my subclass.

Instead I tried monkey patching below, but my `notify()` is never called. I suspect `notify()` is a wrapped C++ method and it can't be monkey patched?

```
def monkey_patch_event_timing(app: QApplication):
    original_notify = app.notify

    def notify_with_timing(self, receiver, event):
        timer_name = _get_timer_name(receiver, event)

        # Time the event while we handle it.
        with perf.perf_timer(timer_name, "qt_event"):
            return original_notify(receiver, event)

    bound_notify = MethodType(notify_with_timing, app)

    # Check if we are already patched first.
    if not hasattr(app, '_myproject_event_timing'):
        print("Enabling Qt Event timing...")
        app.notify = bound_notify
        app._myproject_event_timing = True
```

Is there a way to monkey patch `QApplication.notify` or otherwise insert code somewhere that can time every Qt Event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to remove the old QApplication with the help of sip and create a new one:

```
def monkey_patch_event_timing():

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is not None:
        import sip
        sip.delete(app)

    class MyApplication(QApplication):
        def notify(self, receiver, event):
            ret = QApplication.notify(self, receiver, event)
            print(ret, receiver, event)
            return ret

    app = MyApplication([])
    return app
```

Comment: I have a feeling this will break Jupyter. Seems like something would be referring to the existing QApplication? But it might be worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: Try and tell me if it works, I don't use jupyter so I haven't tested it but I think it shouldn't break anything, obviously that code should be executed at the beginning of the application (before creating any other Qt element). On the other hand, your solution does not work because sip (the tool that creates PyQt5) creates a cache of the methods the first time it is used, so probably when you use your patch it will already invoke "notify by default" so that your "new notify" will not be invoked

Comment: Wow this totally works fine. I just tested it inside Jupyter. I'd be nervous do to something like this by default for all users. But this code path will only run if you explicitly turn on this type of profiling. Only developers will do this. Great, this is a huge help.